# Trying to parse values out of a string using ttp in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to parse out some values from the results of an easysnmp SNMP query but it is not working as expected.

The following results in an error:

```
from ttp import ttp
a = "<SNMPVariable value='1' (oid='enterprises.4998.1.1.20.2.33.1.5.16.86.17.126.66.140.34214089.5', oid_index='', snmp_type='INTEGER')>"
t = "<SNMPVariable value='{{value}}' (oid='{{oid}}', oid_index='{{oid_index}}', snmp_type='{{snmp_type}}')>"
p = ttp(a,t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ttp\ttp.py", line 1168, in parse_template_XML
    template_ET = ET.XML(template_text)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 32
```

If I remove the wedges from the string I do not get an error, but I don't get the values I'm looking for:

```
from ttp import ttp
a = "SNMPVariable value='1' (oid='enterprises.4998.1.1.20.2.33.1.5.16.86.17.126.66.140.34214089.5', oid_index='', snmp_type='INTEGER')"
t = "SNMPVariable value='{{value}}' (oid='{{oid}}', oid_index='{{oid_index}}', snmp_type='{{snmp_type}}')"
p = ttp(a,t)
p.parse()
p.result()
[[{}]]
```

What I expect to get for output is:

```
[[{'value':'1', 'oid':'enterprises.4998.1.1.20.2.33.1.5.16.86.17.126.66.140.34214089.5', 'oid_index'='', 'snmp_type': 'INTEGER'}]]
```

I know I'm overlooking something obvious, but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you getting that string you're using as input? Can you include the part where you're using `easysnmp` to perform the query? Don't know this particular library but from [reading their docs](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp#quick-start) it seems like queries return an object that already contains some of the values you're looking to parse out as attributes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I am asking for someone else and I haven't been able to get back to their code. Will update as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This would parse it properly:

```
from ttp import ttp
a = "SNMPVariable value='1'(oid='enterprises.4998.1.1.20.2.33.1.5.16.86.17.126.66.140.34214089.5', oid_index='', snmp_type='INTEGER')"
t = "SNMPVariable value='{{value}}' (oid='{{oid}}', oid_index='{{oid_index | re('.*')}}', snmp_type='{{snmp_type}}')"
p = ttp(a,t)
p.parse()
p.result()
```

Notice in your data `oid_index=''`, TTP by default uses `\S+` as a regex for variables, but `\S+` would not match emtpy `''`

Alternatively you can use this template:

```
t = "SNMPVariable value='{{value}}' (oid='{{oid}}', oid_index={{oid_index | strip("'")}}, snmp_type='{{snmp_type}}')"
```

In that case `oid_index={{oid_index | strip("'")}}` (no single quotes) will match on `''` but `strip("'")` would remove them.

Both approaches produce same output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "oid": "enterprises.4998.1.1.20.2.33.1.5.16.86.17.126.66.140.34214089.5",
            "oid_index": "",
            "snmp_type": "INTEGER",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Tried this under Python 3.7, but I get an empty result: [[{}]]

Comment: Hm, was running above code on python 3.6, will give it a try on python3.7.